# Pass Current Object Key

Tags: javascript

Is there any way to pass the current key of an object as a parameter to a method executed as its value? For example:

```
VersionOne: {
     welcomeMessage: this.localization.get(this.currentKey(?))
},
VersionTwo: {
    welcomeMessage: this.localization.get(this.currentKey(?))
}
```

I know that I can just write out the keys manually, but for long keys, I don't want to duplicate them.

Comment: You mean while the object is being constructed? That will be impossible.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it before the object has been defined, but you can keep your code DRY by assigning it later:

```js
const versions = {};
['VersionOne', 'VersionTwo'].forEach((version) => {
  versions[version] = {
    welcomeMessage: () => console.log(version),
  };
});
versions.VersionTwo.welcomeMessage();
```

Comment: You can also use `reduce` instead of `forEach`, that would be better.